# SubSonic 3 ActiveRecord lambda expression partially ignored on delete

Tags: linq, activerecord, subsonic, lambda, subsonic3

I have tables Users, Widgets and Layouts. Users have many-to-many relationship with Widgets via Layouts. Each Layout has UserID and WidgetID. I want to delete a Layout that matches specific UserID and WidgetID.

Using SubSonic 3 ActiveRecord I write:

```
Layout.Delete(x => x.UserID == user.id && x.WidgetID == id);
```

However, SubSonic deletes *all* widget layouts for the user, seemingly ignoring the second part of the condition. Am I doing it wrong, or is this a SubSonic bug? If latter, are there any workarounds?

Added later: I fixed it temporarily in Context.tt in my project's Models subdirectory:

```
diff --git a/Models/Context.tt b/Models/Context.tt
index ee64200..dd47510 100644
--- a/Models/Context.tt
+++ b/Models/Context.tt
@@ -162,8 +162,8 @@ namespace <#=Namespace#>
         LambdaExpression lamda = column;
         SqlQuery result = new Delete<T>(this.Provider);
         result = result.From<T>();
-        SubSonic.Query.Constraint c = lamda.ParseConstraint();
-        result.Constraints.Add(c);
+        var q = new QueryVisitor();
+        result.Constraints.AddRange(q.GetConstraints(lamda));
         return result;
     }
```

Comment: Yes - please add this as an issue. Shouldn't be happening...

Comment: I have the same issue with a Find. var items = Person.Find(x => x.ID == id && x.Name == myStringArray[0]); myStringArray is populated!

Comment: Filed a new issue: http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues/#issue/55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug in SubSonic to me. You should report it to [github](http://github.com/subsonic)

In the meantime this code might workaround the issue:

```
Layout layout = Layout.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserID == user.id && x.WidgetID == id);
layout.Delete();
```